# Installed Ubuntu on chromebook, Ubuntu asks for password that wasn't ever set

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, chromebook, chromeos

I installed ubuntu 12.04 on my chromebook.
It didn't asked me for a password at first, but when I attempted to install a software from the store it's asking me for a password which I never set.

As in chromebook, it doesn't have a normal BIOS to reset the password, Please tell me how can I reset the password or if there is any other way.

Answer (score 3):

The password is *user*

I did the same to my Chromebook.